# Sending an SMTP email in Dart

Tags: email, dart

I looked through the API documentation and language guide, but I did not see anything about sending emails in Dart. I also checked this [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/5YNvrmaWiDo), but it's quite old by Dart standards.

Is this possible to do? I know that I can always use the Process class to invoke external programs, but I'd prefer a real Dart solution if there's any.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a library called [`mailer`](https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer), which does exactly what you asked for: sends out emails.

Set it as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` and run `pub install`:

```
dependencies:
  mailer: any
```

I will give a simple example using Gmail on my local Windows machine:

```dart
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';

main() {
  var options = new GmailSmtpOptions()
    ..username = 'kaisellgren@gmail.com'
    ..password = 'my gmail password'; // If you use Google app-specific passwords, use one of those.

  // As pointed by Justin in the comments, be careful what you store in the source code.
  // Be extra careful what you check into a public repository.
  // I'm merely giving the simplest example here.

  // Right now only SMTP transport method is supported.
  var transport = new SmtpTransport(options);

  // Create the envelope to send.
  var envelope = new Envelope()
    ..from = 'support@yourcompany.com'
    ..fromName = 'Your company'
    ..recipients = ['someone@somewhere.com', 'another@example.com']
    ..subject = 'Your subject'
    ..text = 'Here goes your body message';

  // Finally, send it!
  transport.send(envelope)
    .then((_) => print('email sent!'))
    .catchError((e) => print('Error: $e'));
}
```

The `GmailSmtpOptions` is just a helper class. If you want to use a local SMTP server:

```dart
var options = new SmtpOptions()
  ..hostName = 'localhost'
  ..port = 25;
```

You can [check here for all possible fields](https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/blob/master/lib/src/smtp/smtp_options.dart) in the `SmtpOptions` class.

Here's an example using the popular [Rackspace Mailgun](https://mailgun.com/):

```dart
var options = new SmtpOptions()
  ..hostName = 'smtp.mailgun.org'
  ..port = 465
  ..username = 'postmaster@yourdomain.com'
  ..password = 'from mailgun';
```

The library supports HTML emails and attachments as well. Check out [the example](https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer#sending-an-email-with-smtp) to learn how to do that.

I am personally using `mailer` with Mailgun in production use.

Comment: FYI, be careful with application-specific passwords. They bypass 2-factor auth and are not limited to a specific application like the name might imply. I would never place one in source code. _Maybe_ you could feel safe loading it out of a secure key storage service.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that I never intended anyone to store such in source code! Updated example.

Comment: In case of Google, I'd never feel safe storing such passwords. I'd at most store an email service specific password, like in case of most email services such as Mailgun. Thanks for the note.

Comment: When I use gmail with mailer, I get error message: "Error: Failed to send an email: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <xxxx> Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.". I tried to enable IMAP settings in gmail but in vain. What should I do now?

Comment: Will this code run on iOS, even if I am using Flutter?

Comment: Please can you tell me what is Mailgun and what its uses? ..

Answer (score 1):

without using  any library you can try this please improve my answer some errors

```
SecureSocket.connect('smtp.hostinger.com',
  465,
).then((socket) {
socket.write("EHLO smtp.hostinger.com\n");
socket.write("AUTH LOGIN userName(base64String)\r\n");
socket.write("password(base64String)\r\n");
socket.write("MAIL FROM:amra@freeshopping.website\n");
socket.write("RCPT TO:techamra@gmail.com\n");
socket.listen((event) {

String string=String.fromCharCodes(event);
print(string);
},onError: (error){
  print(error);
},onDone: (){
  print("on DONE");
});
```

});`

Answer (score 0):

**== Updated Answer:**

You can use official [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) library from pub.dev:
Add mailer library below your `dependencies:` at `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
mailer: ^3.2.1
```

Then make sure to import those two lines:

```
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';
```

And you can create this method and use it wherever you want: (This is a example to send SMTP mail for Gmail)

```
void sendMail() async {

String username = 'username@gmail.com';
String password = 'password';

  final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
  final equivalentMessage = Message()
  ..from = Address(username, 'Your name')
  ..recipients.add(Address('destination@example.com'))
  ..ccRecipients.addAll([Address('destCc1@example.com'), 'destCc2@example.com'])
  ..bccRecipients.add('bccAddress@example.com')
  ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${DateTime.now()}'
  ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
  ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>Hey! Here's some HTML content</p>";

  await send(equivalentMessage, smtpServer);
  }
}
```

But make sure that you enable ([Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)) at your Gmail Account Settings > Security to successfully integrate with your Email and send this mail.

- Documentation & full example: https://pub.dev/packages/mailer

Comment: It's not useful if every user have to enable less-sucure-app-access. I struggling to find a secure way to send email like with 'gmailRelaySaslXoauth2' that mailer recommended.

Comment: Do one more setting although your username and password are correct with less secure app access but it can throw SmtpClientAuthenticationException. You can resolve it by Go to Settings>Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Enable IMAP access , it will not show any error now