# Is there any IMAP packages published on Dart pub?

Tags: email, dart

I know there's a mailer package for sending emails however I need a comprehensive IMAP library like the [javamail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) one, which supports gmail extensions so I can retrieve all conversations and the email contents/attachments for a certain thread.

Is Google planning to publish a package for Gmail support or is there anybody planning to write one himself?

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822578/sending-an-smtp-email-in-dart?

Comment: I might write an IMAP package some day as I remember the protocol well, but I can't promise anything regarding my use of time. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know, there is no IMAP package. As referenced in the comments, there is the [mailer](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mailer) package on Pub that lets you send email with SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to interface into a javascript library such as https://github.com/emailjs.

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a wrapper for that javascript library yet.